# How to GROUP BY into separate columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have 3 tables:

- The first one contains information about persons. The relevant column is the `personID`.
- The second contains exercises a person can do. There are for example 3 exercises with an `exID`.
- The third contains the points a person (`personID`) reached in an exercise (`exID`). So each row here stands for an examination a person has taken. But not everyone need to have taken every exam.

What I would like to have is a result with the columns `personID`, `exam_one`, `exam_two`, `exam_three`, ...(ongoing, depending on how many exams there are). And each row of the result should contain the `personID` and the points from the respective exam.

For exams not taken there should be NULL or something.

Example for table persons:

```
personID | Name  | ...
-------------------
 1       | Max   |
 2       | Peter |
```

Example for exercises table:

```
exID | exName | maxPoints | ...
-------------------------------
 1   | exam1  | 20
 2   | exam2  | 25
 3   | exam3  | 20
```

Example for points table:

```
personID (fkey) | exID (fkey) | points
----------------------------------------
     1          |    1        |  12.5
     1          |    3        |  10
     2          |    1        |   5
     2          |    2        |   8.5
     2          |    3        |  10
```

Wished result:

```
personId | exam1 | exam2 | exam3
------------------------------------
   1     | 12.5  | NULL  | 10
   2     |  5    |  8.5  | 10
```

Is there a way to do this? I use **PostgreSQL**

Comment: Many ways to do this, yes. Please provide an example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please provide schema, sample data and desired output.

Comment: There's Pivot Tables, but your question lack relevant info, like DBMS used and table structure. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like the following:

```
select p.personId,
  sum(case when e.exname = 'exam1' then t.points end) Exam1,
  sum(case when e.exname = 'exam2' then t.points end) Exam2,
  sum(case when e.exname = 'exam3' then t.points end) Exam3
from persons p
left join points t
  on p.personID = t.personID
left join exercises e
  on t.exid = e.exid
group by p.personid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/0d050/5)

Comment: Works fine but it is not flexible enough. There can be more or less exams and the names can differ. I do not know what exactly the exercises table will contain